# MongoDB aggregate lookup with multiple "ON" criteria

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections in MongoDB with some arrays and nested arrays inside and I would like to lookup or something else considering two foreign keys.

Collection structure:

**Stocks**

```
{
 merchantIds: ["abc"],
 products: [
  {
   code: "123",
   quantity: 10
  },
  {
   code: "456",
   quantity: 15
  },
  {
   code: "999",
   quantity: 99
  }
 ]
}
```

**Orders**

```
{
 id: "123456789",
 items: [
  {
   name: "aaa",
   externalCode: "123",
   quantity: 1,
   options: [
    {
     name: "ccc",
     externalCode: "999",
     quantity: 2,
    }
   ],
  },
  {
   name: "bbb",
   externalCode: "456",
   quantity: 2,
   options: [
    name: "aaa",
    externalCode: "123",
    quantity: 5,
   ]
  },
  {
   name: "ddd",
   externalCode: "789",
   quantity: 2,
   options: []
  }
 ]
}
```

I would like to create an aggregation pipeline between both collections to get this result:

```
[
 {
  name: "aaa",
  externalCode: "123"
 },
 {
  name: "bbb",
  externalCode: "456"
 },
 {
  name: "ccc",
  externalCode: "999"
 }
]
```

How could I consider both `items.externalCode` and `items.options.externalCode` in an aggregate pipeline and reduce to this result?

Comment: How do you associate `{name: "bbb", externalCode: "456"}`?

Comment: I would like to filter all stocks products associating code with items or items.options externalCode, and then I would like to get its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the followings in an aggregation pipeline:

1. flatten the `items` and `items.options` array by using `$map` and `$reduce`
2. create a union array of the results above using `$setUnion`
3. `$lookup` to the `stocks` collection. In the sub-pipeline, specify your join criteria
4. `$unwind` to prune the unmatched result

```js
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      id: "123456789"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      items: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$items",
          "as": "i",
          "in": {
            name: "$$i.name",
            externalCode: "$$i.externalCode"
          }
        }
      },
      options: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$items",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$value",
              {
                "$reduce": {
                  "input": "$$this.options",
                  "initialValue": [],
                  "in": {
                    "$concatArrays": [
                      "$$value",
                      [
                        {
                          name: "$$this.name",
                          externalCode: "$$this.externalCode"
                        }
                      ]
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      union: {
        "$setUnion": [
          "$items",
          "$options"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$union"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "stocks",
      let: {
        extCode: "$union.externalCode"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            merchantIds: "abc"
          }
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              "$in": [
                "$$extCode",
                "$products.code"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "lookupResult"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$lookupResult"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      externalCode: "$union.externalCode",
      name: "$union.name"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YQ8E0rkw-6j) for your reference.

Comment: Yes, it's something like that, but I don't want to have repeated names and externalCodes, in output.

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes the duplicates should be handled already in the `$setUnion`. Kindly provide a test case if the solution does not work and we will see what can be fixed.

Comment: Hi @ray! I already did changes and I think it's fine now. I added ```{$group: {_id: '$union.externalCode', name: {$first: '$union.name' }, externalCode: { $first: '$union.externalCode' } }}``` 
after ```{"$unwind": "$union"}``` and then the duplicated was gone. If you have a better solution, please share it with me, the test case could be used the same as the provided in the question

Comment: The modified playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/c4TNnmGzw-a

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes I think your new `$group` stage is already the best for current structure. If possible, I would try to change the db schema to make `options` on the same layer as `items` instead of a nested structure. It could make the query easier and simpler.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for advance! It helped me a lot.